# How to set Debian to automatically update time and date?

Tags: linux, debian, time

I have an old computer and BIOS counts the time slower than real ;)

So, how can I set my OS to update the time automatically using the internet?

If it updated the time only during booting, it would be enough.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the time during system boot actually, and from the [Debian Documentation](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/system-administrator/ch-sysadmin-time.html#s-syncing-time) they even specify it for use on hardware that doesn't keep track of time properly. I recommend using NTP though. You can set it up to connect to an NTP server. First install NTP though, using

```
$ sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Once it's installed, navigate to /etc/ntp.conf which you can edit using your favourite text edit. Say, gedit or nano.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/ntp.conf
```

I'm not sure if it needs sudo, but you can use it anyway.

You need to know an NTP server to set this. Modify your file to be like so:

```
 logfile /var/log/xntpd
 driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
 statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

 statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
 filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
 filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
 filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

 server ntp.somedomain.something
 server ntp.something.else
```

Replace the somedomain.something and something.else with NTP servers. You can find some hfrom the [NTP server home](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/WebHome).

Answer (score 26):

If you have `systemd` in [version](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-timesyncd#Installation) greater than `213` (check: `systemd --version`), you don't have to install `ntp` package to synchronize system time.

`systemd` provides [`systemd-timesyncd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-timesyncd) daemon which implements [SNTP](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4330.txt) (Simple NTP) client.

To start and enable SNTP synchronization:

```
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

To show current settings of the system clock and [RTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock):

```
timedatectl status
```

Configuration of `systemd-timesyncd` daemon is in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` file. You can provide your NTP servers there. By default all servers are commented out and NTP servers are [obtained](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-timesyncd#Configuration) from `systemd-networkd.service(8)` configuration or via DHCP.

If you have installed *Windows* alongside *Linux*, you may struggle with dual-boot system time [issues](https://superuser.com/questions/884278/windows-vs-linux-local-time). The reason is simple: Windows keeps hardware clock in local time and Linux in UTC time (`timedatectl set-local-rtc 1` may be helpful but [is not](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html#set-local-rtc%20%5BBOOL%5D) recommended; you'd better [change](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Time#UTC_in_Windows) *Windows* time settings to force keeping hardware clock in UTC).

Comment: awesome answer for those using Debian 8. Thank you!

Comment: Workin' fine on Debian 10 too!

Comment: If you installed Debian in minimal mode, the `systemd-timesyncd` service will not be available and the `timedatectl set-ntp true` will give you an error. Just run `sudo apt install systemd-timesyncd`.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
sudo systemctl restart ntp
sudo systemctl enable ntp
```

That's it. Just run `$ date` to see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

Install ntp and made it run on runlevels 2,3,5. Then it will pull the date and time from well-known sources and will adjust your system gradually.

Comment: Ntp seems to be what i'm searching. But how can i set to runlevels 2,3,5 without gui tool?