# Time difference on dual boot system (Windows 10 and 16.04)

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, uefi, time

I have a dual boot UEFI system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed. I have a problem related to the representation of RTC in the two system.

Since I have read (on AU and some other sources around the Web) that Ubuntu (and others like OSX) uses the correct way to interpret RTC I decided to solve my problem there (I hope it is not a off-topic question here because of that, it is connected to Ubuntu and frankly I did not want to mess with the time settings of my Ubuntu).

So I have read about the RealTimeIsUniversal registry setting. I have set it up as a QWORD (since it is an x64 OS), saved then ran

```
sc config w32time start= disabled
```

as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot?noredirect=1&lq=1), but unfortunately it does not work. My time in uefi sets 2 hours back by that (10:42 vs. 12:42) and before login I can see Ubuntu sets itself to 14:42.

What should I do now?

Thanks!

Comment: I have solved the problem by executing: timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 under Ubuntu but is there a reliable solution under Windows to migrate to UTC from localtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows vs Linux Local Time?](https://superuser.com/questions/884278/windows-vs-linux-local-time)