# How to config time/timezone correctly?

Tags: windows-10, time

I have the following OS: `Win10` and `Ubuntu 16.04` working in dual boot, with `UEFI` and `SECURE MODE DISABLED`.

The time/hour settings is correct in `Ubuntu` and `BIOS/UEFI` setup, but in Windows it is incorrect! When reconfig and reboot system, he lost the correct hour.

Now, in my town is `22:23 GMT -3` but Windows insists its `01:23`.

What is going on?

[image: Windows Timezone]

Comment: This may be the issue. -http://lifehacker.com/5742148/fix-windows-clock-issues-when-dual-booting-with-os-x

Comment: Relevant: [Time difference on dual boot system (Windows 10 and 16.04)](https://superuser.com/q/1099444)

Comment: @RandySchuman thanks, solved. But I would like to know the cause of the problem.